# want to execute jquery in document.write element within dynamically written html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

My QR code is showing in my asp.net web page but when I try to open print dialog box its not loading the JavaScript and the QR code is not showing in print box .. I tried all options to load jQuery in Dynamically created html window but no use... the code goes like this

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">

    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery.qrcode.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/qrcode.js" />
    </Scripts>

</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>



    <asp:Panel id="pnlContents" runat = "server">
         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <table style="width: 40%;">
             <tr>
                 <td>Name</td>
                 <td><h3><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></h3></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Company</td>
                 <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company") %></td>

             </tr>
             <tr>

                 <td><div id ="qrcode" ><h5>HELLO</h5>
                      <script type = "text/javascript">
                          jQuery('#qrcode').qrcode({ width: 100, height: 100, text: "Name:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")%> Company:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company") %> Mobile:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Mobile") %>" });
</script> </div></td>

             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><h3><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RegType")%></h3></td>

             </tr>
         </table>



 <script type = "text/javascript">
     function PrintPanel() {
         var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");

         var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
         printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print ID</title> <style type="text/css">body { margin: 264.566929px 0px 0px 0px; } </style>');
         printWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.qrcode.js"><\/sc'+'ript>');
         printWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/qrcode.js"><\/sc' + 'ript>');
         printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
         printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
         printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
         printWindow.document.close();
         setTimeout(function () {
             printWindow.print();
         }, 500);
         return false;
     }
</script>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater> 





</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" class="btn btn-warning" runat="server" Text="Print"  OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel();"  Visible="false"/>
```

Comment: did you try passing the absolute url for the scripts?

Comment: no i didnt use an absolute url .. I am getting the values from database from code behind.. I am using a nuget package for generating QR. QR is generated in main page but when the print dialog box it's not showing the QR ..

Answer (score 0):

i was just forgeting to add the reference to jquery Script.. Thanx for help